# SAS split macro string with delimiter

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to give variables proper names in SAS macro, however, I either got error message or  got first letter of the string. Here is an example using following SAS codes:

```
data trial; 
  %let cate=gender age;
  %let label="Gender*Age at dx";
    do i=1 to countw("&cate");
      item=scan("&cate",i) ;  
      print=scan(%str(&label),i,*);
      output;
   end;
run;
```

I got error like this:

> ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.
> 25385        print=scan(%str(&label),i,*);

> ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

> ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

If I change the codes like this:

```
data trial;
  %let cate=gender age;
  %let label="Gender*Age at dx";
    do i=1 to countw("&cate");
      item=scan("&cate",i) ;  
      print=scan(%str(&label),i);
      output;
   end;
run;
```

I get print=Age instead of print='Age at dx'.
Any hints on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotation marks around your delimeter, `*`, in the `scan()` function. You also do not need to use `%str()`.

```
print=scan(&label, i, '*');
```

Output:

```
i   item    print
1   gender  Gender
2   age     Age at dx
```

I would also recommend placing your `%let` statements before your data step to make it a bit easier to read.

```
%let cate=gender age;
%let label="Gender*Age at dx";

data trial; 
    ...;
run;
```

Comment: Yes, adding  quotation marks works.  Thanks for you suggestion!